# How to pass just created object id to other form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hello I want to to pass just created object id to other form, but not sure how to do it.
Right now my submit button tries to submit form and then redirect to other component modal which opens other form. Other form one of parameters is just created object id. Whats the correct way to solve this problem?

```
<Form.Group>
   <ButtonToolbar>
       <Button variant="primary"  type = "submit" onClick
       ={()=>this.setState({addSkillShow:true})}>Add Application</Button>
       =<AddSkillModal
       show={this.state.addSkillShow}
       onHide={addSkillClose}
       applicationId={applicationId}/>
   </ButtonToolbar>
</Form.Group>
```

Comment: So where is this "created object"? Assuming that you handle the creation and properties of this object, you would have to somehow pass it into the modal you're opening. This can be done via [component props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html), [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or any other way of shared state management.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.